Any way to map camera to screen share?

Some apps like WhatsApp require the user to scan a qr code on the phone to access certain parts of it (WhatsApp web, 2chat API etc., for example).
The problem is if one only has one device, the mobile Android phone, and no desktop computer at hand nor any other device. Practically one can't take a video of the screen with the camera
UNLESS, there was a way to trick the app into thinking it's getting picture data from the camera, when in reality it is getting data from the screen.
On Android phones one can record the screen into a video file.
Theoretically it should be possible to get that video stream and somehow "map" it to the camera input, such that if one uses any app that accesses the camera, it would really access the screen itself.
Is there an app to do this already? If not, can this be done? It's root permission needed?
On desktop devices, this technique would be referred to as a virtual webcam, although I'm not sure if the same terminology applies to Android devices in this context

Possibly a dupe of How to emulate camera input in Android? (To activate WhatsApp Web), which I'm afraid after more than 5 years, there's no proper answer yet.
